# How Kerberos krb5p does encryption?

Tags: encryption, kerberos

All,

I am trying to mount a NAS drive to a Linux VM.
I have a requirement to encrypt the data in transit, i.e. I want data to be encrypted when
its written from the Linux to the NAS dribe

https://www.dellemc.com/hu-hu/collaterals/unauth/technical-guides-support-information/products/storage/docu88304.pdf

As per the above link krb5p provides encryption of data.
krb5p: Kerberos authentication, data integrity, and data privacy by encrypting the data before sending it over the network. Data encryption requires additional

https://www.varonis.com/blog/kerberos-authentication-explained/
I understand how Kerberos mutual-authentication works but once access is granted to the service (in my case the NAS drive) how does the data transferred to the NAS gets encrypted.
Can someone provide additional details or documentation on how "encryption" works with krb5p?
I am unable to find any additional details.

As per:
https://whyistheinternetbroken.wordpress.com/tag/krb5p/
when using krb5p:
NFS packets will be encrypted with the enctype specified in the Kerberos configuration.

But what are the available enctype that can be specified?

I have attached a diagram that tries to explain the flow of messages b/w Server-KDC-Client
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos allows mutual authentication between a client and a KDC, the KDC and a service, and a client and a service. This happens by way of key agreement between each party.

Client and KDC prove knowledge of a shared key, KDC and service prove knowledge of a different shared key, so client and service can generate yet another random key and agree with one another.

In other words when the client sends the ticket to the service it contains a secret key that both parties can use to encrypt data after authentication has succeeded. In this case that key is what is used to protect NFS traffic.

What enctype is selected is somewhat undefined. It's up to all three parties to agree on one, and each has an opportunity to change it. In practice it's up to the service to make the final decision though. It should be whatever it thinks the strongest algorithm the client can handle. This usually means RC4, AES128, or AES256.

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos just provides the encryption key, but it doesn't magically perform the encryption itself – that has to be done by the NFS client and NFS server themselves. They are aware that krb5p was negotiated, and will call the corresponding encryption/decryption functions when needed. (More specifically, it happens in the SunRPC layer, which NFS is built on.)

---

When the Kerberos KDC issues you a ticket for "nfs/yourserver.example.com", that ticket includes two copies of a randomly generated session key: one copy decryptable by you, and the other copy decryptable by that server.

The KDC will mark this session key with the best enctype that is common between what was indicated in your ticket request, and what long-term keys are held by the server's principal. Usually this will be AES256-CTS, though it can be RC4 (arcfour) if the service key hasn't been changed in a very long time.

For example,

- The "nfs/yourserver.example.com" principal has long-term keys for aes256-cts-sha1-96, aes128-cts-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac, des3-cbc.
- Your client making the AS_REQ indicates support for aes256-cts-sha384, aes128-cts-sha256, aes256-cts-sha1-96, aes128-cts-sha1-96.
- The KDC chooses aes256-cts-sha1-96 as the best enctype for the session key.

This indication is stored *in the ticket itself*. If the client is using MIT Krb5 software, you can use `kvno` to manually request a service ticket (if you don't have one yet) and then `klist -e` to see the enctypes set for that ticket – "skey" indicates the enctype that the session key is meant to be used with.

So after receiving the ticket from the KDC, you send it to the NFS server as part of the RPCSEC_GSS authentication process, and now both you and the server have copies of the session key. (The same session key remains in use for as long as the service ticket is valid – usually 10 hours.)

---

The set of [possible enctypes](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/enctypes.html#enctype-compatibility) is:

- `aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192`, `aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128`: New, not supported by most implementations yet (and most services won't have keys of that type yet, either).
- `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`, `aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96`: Widely supported by all Kerberos implementations.
- `camellia256-cts-cmac`, `camellia128-cts-cmac`: Decent alternatives to AES, but rarely used in practice.
- `arcfour-hmac` (RC4): Deprecated, but still occassionally used. Gone from Linux 5.10.
- `des3-cbc-sha1`: Deprecated, but still implemented.
- `des-cbc-md5`, `des-cbc-crc`: Completely obsolete. Hope you'll never see those.

(Don't believe webpages saying that Linux NFS client only supports DES – that was fixed in 2010 for v2.6.35, and AES is fully supported now.)

Comment: Hi, This point is not clear:
"The KDC will mark this session key with the best enctype that is common between what was indicated in your ticket request, and what long-term keys are held by the server's principal."

KDC in my case is an Active Directory Domain Controller.
So is the "enctype" some type of parameter I have to set within my AD?                           
 So once after the authentication is complete, will subsequent communication from my Limux VM to the NAS file server also use the same Symmetric Service Session Key that is shared b/w the server and client?

Comment: @user2595169: In the case of AD DC, it's set using the [msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MsDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes) attribute on the user account or computer account. (If it's not set, only RC4 is assumed.) For user objects who have SPNs, you can see checkboxes in the "Advanced" view in dsa.msc that correspond to this, e.g. "This account supports AES256 encryption". I just upgraded an account from RC4 to AES256 a few minutes ago. (For computer objects usually the correct value is set at join time.)

Comment: @user2595169: Once the authentication is complete, all communications using that ticket will use the same symmetric session key. (Note that the session key isn't actually used _for_ authentication – it's merely delivered _during_ authentication. Don't confuse it with the long-term service key!)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, one last question - at which point do I set the krb5p as an option? Is it when mounting the NAS to the Linux VM. I can see the following command was used in centos and I suppose we are asking KDC to make it mandatory encrypt data during transit, is that right?                                            
   mount -t nfs -o sec=krb5p server.example.com:/export /mnt/export
The above command was taken from: https://serverfault.com/questions/871899/why-is-o-sec-krb5p-unnecessary-in-the-mount-command

Comment: Primarily you need to set it on the NAS itself, when marking the filesystem for export (/etc/exports or equivalent), but for safety's sake you should also set it when mounting the filesystem: `-o sec=krb5p`. (Technically clients will automatically choose the best method offered by the server, but there might not be downgrade protection from krb5p to e.g krb5i or krb5.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.